# How to show bluetooth headphone battery in macos?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, catalina

Hovering over the device doesn't show the battery level.
When connected to the iPhone, I was able to get the battery level in the widgets screen.

[image]

How do I know when I have to charge the headphones?

Comment: Check out this question if you wish to develop something yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55785359/how-can-i-get-iobluetoothdevices-battery-level-using-swift-and-appkit-xcode-f

Answer (score 4):

You can write your custom script on these lines

https://romig.dev/blog/mac-os-quirks-bluetooth-device-battery-low/  using ioreg I/O Registry, code for a implementation is available here on Github https://github.com/aromig/scripts/tree/master/check_battery

You can also use plugins like Akku https://github.com/jariz/Akku

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/295232) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes or disappears.

Comment: modified to include github code link in case the main blog vanishes. ioreg reference should help point in right direction, thanks for feedback @Glorfindel

Answer (score 2):

MacOS Monterey now supports 3rd party Bluetooth headsets by itself. This was the reason for plugins like [Akku](https://github.com/jariz/Akku) being discontinued.

Try to upgrade your OS.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something built into macOS.

To get alerts and notifications about your Bluetooth devices’ battery status, you need a third party utility like [MenuBar Stats](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/menubar-stats/id714196447?mt=12).

Comment: There is also Akku, which is available on GitHub: https://github.com/jariz/Akku

Answer (score 1):

On the latest updates of mac os (I have mac os 12.1) you can check the battery of bluetooth-connected devices in the Bluetooth menubar icon:

[image: Bluetooth menubar icon]